# Error in TwiterAgent in Cloudera flume

Tags: twitter, cloudera, flume

execution struck somewhere after this

14/10/02 07:33:31 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel MemChannel type memory
14/10/02 07:33:31 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel MemChannel
14/10/02 07:33:31 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: HDFS, type: hdfs
14/10/02 07:33:32 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
14/10/02 07:33:32 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel MemChannel connected to [HDFS]
14/10/02 07:33:32 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{HDFS=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@72cf095e counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{MemChannel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: MemChannel}} }
14/10/02 07:33:32 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel MemChannel
14/10/02 07:33:33 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel: Successfully registered new MBean.
14/10/02 07:33:33 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: MemChannel started
14/10/02 07:33:33 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink HDFS
14/10/02 07:33:33 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: HDFS: Successfully registered new MBean.
14/10/02 07:33:33 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started

Comment: Can you put some code? In log there isn't any error trace.

Comment: More importantly, need your flume.conf. I don't think you've configured any sources.